# Convert array of characters to string

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
var text = "filler text filler text Michael filler text Michael";
var myName = 'Michael';
var hits = [];
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    if (text[i] === "M"){
        for (var j = i; j < (i + myName.length); j++){
            hits.push(text[j]);
            myName.toString();
        }
    }
}

if (hits === 0){
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

prints out ["M" "i" "c" "h" "a" "e" "l"]
how do I get it to print "Michael"?
Thanks

Comment: `myName.toString();` on a statement by itself isn’t going to do anything. What did you expect it to do? And what is this code supposed to accomplish in general? If you’re trying to match a pattern, use a regular expression. If you’re trying to check for substrings, use `indexOf`.

Comment: Your code searches for only the letter "M", then places the next (myName.length - 1) (in this case 6) letters into `hits`. Look at [the `indexOf()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp), which can search for an entire string. Your code then searches each character after the "M" (the i,c,h,e,a,l) for an "M", which is a little inefficient, could cause errors (if the "M" is closer to the end of `text` than the length of `myName`), and another reason to use `indexOf()`.

Comment: This search algorithm is not guaranteed to only match on Michael. It will match any string of length 7 - starting with an M

Answer (score 2):

Use the `join` method of the Array class.

```
console.log(hits.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest would be to simply join the array:
`hits.join("")`

Answer (score 0):

You can join() function and make sure to indicate the delimiter you want to use. If you want to display it without any delimiter then just use "" as parameter.

```
var name = hits.join("");
console.log(name);
```